# What does it mean for a process that at least one of its causal factors lie in the future?

Tags: causality

In general, a process has many causes, which are said to be causal factors for it, and all lie in its past (more precise: none lie in its future).

What does it mean for a process that at least one of its causal factors lie in the future?

my question is based on the concept of quantum retrocausality, where a decision made in our experience of the present may influence what we experience as the past.

Comment: Buying a car in future is causing me to save money now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality

Comment: As it stands, "quantum retrocausality", or similar effect in the [Wheeler–Feynman absorber theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory) is just a mathematical trick of representing current state as a superposition of "retarded" and "advanced" solutions, where the latter look mathematically as if they "come from the future". It is a nice symmetric presentation, but in both cases the superpositions obey the usual causality. So physically, it does not mean anything. See Wikipedia's [Retrocausality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality).

Comment: @christo183 - Yes, but wanting to but a car in the future is a current cause, not a future cause.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm saving now, _in case_ I want to buy a car in future?